# How to get the last id of a MySQL database table, and store it in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a website and I want to display user reviews in a Bootstrap carousel. I want to display only the latest 3 feedbacks. The latest review has to have a class "active". In order to do that, I need the last id not just after inserting into the table, but throughout the whole website. I have tried this so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM comments";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $last_id = $row["id"];
}
```

I know there's a way to get the last_id after inserting a new row, but I will always need the last variable. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: try with this $sql = "SELECT MAX(id)  as id FROM comments";

Comment: `I want to display only the latest 3 feedbacks.` So why do you need to know the max(id) value for this?

Comment: Because the first feedback has to have a class of "active". If there's any more efficient way to do this, please let me know. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id FROM `comments` order by id desc limit 1
```

when you use `SELECT MAX(id) FROM comments` field name in result will be MAX(id) and $row["id"]; will not work

if you want to use MAX use it something like this `SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM comments`

Comment: So what is the error in **SELECT MAX(id) FROM comments**

Comment: in this case field name in result will be MAX(id) and this $row["id"]; will not work if you want to use max use it something like this MAX(id) as id

Comment: Yes. You should have added this to your answer too. what say?

Comment: Thank you. After this how do I store it in a variable?

Comment: Never mind, I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}   
 $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    //I guess this is the line you're lookin for
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```